# Modal pop up in JavaScript won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to make simple pop up window using javascript with ASP.NET web forms.

I have following code:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/BankInformation.ascx" TagName="BankInformation" TagPrefix="ABS" %>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var bankInformation = $('#<%=bankInformation.ClientID%>');
            var sameAsMerchantBankCheckbox = $('#<%=chkSameAsMerchantBank.ClientID%>');
            function OpenDirectDebitDialog(dialogID) {
                $("#" + dialogID).modal();
            }

            function ValidateAndCloseDirectDebitDialog(validationGroup, dialogID) {
                var pageValid = Page_ClientValidate(validationGroup);
                if (pageValid)
                    $("#" + dialogID).modal("hide");
            }

            $(sameAsMerchantBankCheckbox).change(function () {
                OpenDirectDebitDialog(bankInformation);
            });
        });
    </script>

    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkDirectDebit" />
    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="chkSameAsMerchantBank" ID="txtDirectDebit" meta:resourcekey="lblDirectDebit"></asp:Label>
    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkSameAsMerchantBank" AutoPostBack="True" Checked="True" />
    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtSameAsMerchantBank" ID="txtSameAsMerchantBank" meta:resourcekey="lblSameAsMerchantBank"></asp:Label>

    <div id="bankInfoDialog" runat="server" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <ABS:BankInformation runat="server" ID="bankInformation" />
    </div>
```

On deselecting chkSameAsMerchantBank checkbox event should fire and OpenDirectDebitDialog function should be invoked. But all that happens is page refresh(auto post back I guess). No errors or anything in browser console.
Does anybody sees what I'm doing wrongly? Can I even invoke hidden form on modal like this?

Comment: you have to use `ClienID`.

Comment: The ID used in Jquery selector is wrong. Try using "chkSameAsMerchantBank" as ID like $(chkSameAsMerchantBank).change(function () ....

Comment: @DfrDkn Oh sorry my mistake, I've missed that line of code in my question, but I do have it. It's defined like this: var sameAsMerchantBankCheckbox = $('#<%=chkSameAsMerchantBank.ClientID%>'); I will add it right away in question.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Thanks for response. I'm using ClientID when creating bankInformation variable. Do you mean not that ClientID or some other?

Comment: Yes problem is their.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do

```
var sameAsMerchantBankCheckbox = $('#<%=chkSameAsMerchantBank.ClientID%>');
```

in your code  then access checkbox Id

Comment: I did that. But still nothing... @ParthTrivedi

Comment: may be problem is simple. Do `$("#bankInfoDialog").modal()`. not to use `bankInformation` ID it is inside popup `div`

Comment: None, that is the problem. Console is empty, no errors to show, but the code is not working still @ParthTrivedi

Comment: I've tried that as well. Not working with those changes as well... @ParthTrivedi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98564/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-nemo-87).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to re create a jQuery id selector again in the function as:

```
 $("#" + dialogID).modal();
```

because the passed argument is already a jQuery object. so just remove the `"#"+` from it.

---

Why? see below:

As this var is a jQuery object:

```
var bankInformation = $('#<%=bankInformation.ClientID%>'); // id selector jq object.
```

You don't have to make it a id selector of it again in the function:

```
var sameAsMerchantBankCheckbox = $('#<%=chkSameAsMerchantBank.ClientID%>');// id selector.
```

which is passed in the function on change event:

```
$(sameAsMerchantBankCheckbox).change(function () { // <----this will do.
    OpenDirectDebitDialog(bankInformation); // <----passed the jQuery selector object here.
});
```

so you just need to do this:

```
function OpenDirectDebitDialog(dialogID) {
   dialogID.modal(); // it would suffice.
   // or $(dialogID).modal(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I did as you've suggested... But still nothing. Modal does not fire up. @Jai